# Import XSD files to MySQL

Tags: mysql, xml, import, xsd

Is there a way to import XSD files to MySQL? PhpMyAdmin seems to only accept SQL files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Altova XMLSpy "generate relational database structures from XML Schemas".